# Getting exception on bean shell assertion for org/json/simple/JSONArray

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

error :_ jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval  org/json/simple/JSONArray

Import java method from project jar file which is placed in lib folder.
source code on written for pass json value in arraylist:

```
import jsonresponse.common.JsonResponseProcessor;
import assertions.AssertResponse;
import databaseresponse.common.DbResponseProcessors;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

String resJson = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
String res = resJson.get("queueId");
log.info("----->>>>"+resJson);

ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add("queueId");
list1.add("name");
list1.add("faxNumber");
list1.add("description"); 
list1.add("type");

ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.add("userId");

ArrayList list3 = new ArrayList();
list3.add("agencyId");

ArrayList list4 = new ArrayList();
list4.add("usertypeId");

JsonResponseProcessor obj = new  JsonResponseProcessor();
System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%fgfggfffgf%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
ArrayList Jsoin = obj.getvalueofsubmapoflist(resJson,".result[0]",list1);
System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" +Jsoin);

log.info(">>>"+Jsoin);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have all referenced .jar files in JMeter classpath (i.e. copy them to JMeter's "lib" folder). Don't forget to **restart JMeter to pick the jars up**
2. If you still experience issues try putting your code inside [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

   ```
   try {
       //your code here
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Problem in Beanshell", ex);
       throw ex;
   }
   ```

   This way you'll have informative stacktrace printed to *jmeter.log* file.
3. One more way to get more information regarding your Beanshell script is putting [debug();](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) directive to the beginning of your code. If will trigger debugging output into [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on using Java and JMeter APIs from Beanshell test elements in JMeter tests.